# chef-client on windows failing with NoSuchMethodError

Tags: chef-infra, http-proxy, winrm

**Pre-requisites**

- Chef Sever is running on a virtual machine hosted on the same isolated network as the node/workstation
- Network does require a proxy to communicate with services on the Internet

**Issue**

Attempting to run 'chef-client' after bootstrapping a **specific** node on windows is resulting in: -

```
knife winrm <machine> chef-client -m -x <user> -P <password> --verbose

[2017-03-15T07:48:28+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 12.19.36 ***
[2017-03-15T07:48:28+00:00] INFO: Platform: x64-mingw32
[2017-03-15T07:48:28+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 16184
[2017-03-15T07:48:50+00:00] INFO: Client key C:\chef\client.pem is not present - registering
[2017-03-15T07:48:50+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2017-03-15T07:48:50+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2017-03-15T07:48:50+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to c:/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2017-03-15T07:48:50+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2017-03-15T07:48:50+00:00] FATAL: NoMethodError: undefined method `closed?' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  clone
```

Correctly, it has not found the client.pem and is using the validator for the first time but upon reading the stack trace,  I can see the root cause is that the machine is unable to acquire the private key from the chef server. See below: -

```
>>>> Caused by Net::HTTPServerException: 407 "Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )"
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http/response.rb:120:in `error!'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http/response.rb:129:in `value'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:920:in `connect'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1398:in `request'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/http/basic_client.rb:70:in `request'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/http.rb:340:in `block in send_http_request'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/http.rb:372:in `block in retrying_http_errors'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/http.rb:370:in `loop'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/http.rb:370:in `retrying_http_errors'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/http.rb:333:in `send_http_request'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/http.rb:148:in `request'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/http.rb:131:in `post'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/api_client/registration.rb:96:in `create'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/api_client/registration.rb:87:in `create_or_update'
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.19.36-universal-mingw32/lib/chef/api_client/registration.rb:58:in `run'
```

**What have I tried?**

Manually creating and downloading the private key from the chef server - still get the 407 at a later stage. This leads me to believe that there actually is some proxy issue however I'm able to communicate with the chef server just fine from the node

I've run the WinRM command using a domain controller's credentials so I'm certain there is no lack of permissions and have enabled the following WinRM settings on the node.

```
cmd.exe /c winrm quickconfig -q
cmd.exe /c winrm quickconfig -transport:http
cmd.exe /c winrm set winrm/config @{MaxTimeoutms="1800000"}
cmd.exe /c winrm set winrm/config/winrs @{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="3000"}
cmd.exe /c winrm set winrm/config/service @{AllowUnencrypted="true"}
cmd.exe /c winrm set winrm/config/service/auth @{Basic="true"}
cmd.exe /c winrm set winrm/config/client/auth @{Basic="true"}
cmd.exe /c winrm set winrm/config/listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTP @{Port="5985"}
cmd.exe /c netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="Windows Remote Management (HTTP-In)" profile=public protocol=tcp localport=5985 remoteip=localsubnet new remoteip=any
cmd.exe /c net stop winrm 
cmd.exe /c sc config winrm start= auto
cmd.exe /c net start winrm
```

**Update** running chef-client local to the machine, without even using WinRM results in the same error. *Leaving WinRM settings and commands in post for historic reference*

**Knife.rb**

```
current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                "admin"
client_key               "#{current_dir}/admin_user.pem"
validation_client_name   'org-validator'
validation_key           "#{current_dir}/org-validator.pem"
chef_server_url          "https://chef.fqdn/organizations/org"
cookbook_path            ["#{current_dir}/../cookbooks"]
```

**Client.rb created by bootstrap process**

```
log_level        :info
log_location     STDOUT

chef_server_url  "https://chef.fqdn/organizations/org"
validation_client_name "org-validator"

file_cache_path   "c:/chef/cache"
file_backup_path  "c:/chef/backup"
cache_options     ({:path => "c:/chef/cache/checksums", :skip_expires => true})

# Using default node name (fqdn)
trusted_certs_dir "c:/chef/trusted_certs"
```

It's worth noting that I'm not having this problem on any other machines on the network. I'm struggling to find any more debugging information from the chef-client or the chef-server.

**ANSWER**

As mentioned in the accepted answer, the machine had HTTP_PROXY set in the windows environment variables which chef recognises and attempts to use. The solution was to add no_proxy to the `client.rb` or to remove the HTTP_PROXY environment variable.

```
no_proxy 'chef.fqdn'
```

Comment: Seems your proxy doesn't like this machine or the account used... That sounds unrelated to chef but more a proxy problem. Without a drawing of your network architecture it's hard to help, do you really need to pass through the proxy to contact your chef server ?

Comment: @Tensibai, updated the post to include details about proxy. Short answer, no, the proxy is only required for pass-through to the outside world. There should be no need for the chef-client to try to use a proxy. I haven't configured a proxy server in the client.rb or anywhere else.

Comment: Your system has the proxy somewhere in its configuration, check your machine client.rb, if you have proxy information in your knife config they are copied to the machine while bootstraping. But what is strange is that you should have a no_proxy entry to contact your chef server also... I'd dig this way to find why chef is trying to use the proxy to contact the chef server, if it's not chef then it's some firewall on your machine which redirect requests to the proxy.

Comment: I can confirm adding `no_proxy 'chef.fqdn'` works, however I'd really like to know why chef picks up the windows http proxy without configuration in the `client.rb`. Most tools require you to specify the proxy information.

Comment: which flavor of windows ? If there's a HTTP_PROXY env variable chef will honor it... I can't really tell how your machine is made

Comment: HTTP_PROXY is indeed set on the machine and it seems like chef honored it, that's the information I was looking for. I didn't realise chef would honor the windows environment variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the proxy isn't required for Chef either unset the proxy environment variables or set no_proxy appropriately.

Comment: The proxy is required for the machine to talk outside of the internal network. Could you point to any documentation where I can instruct chef to specifically not use a proxy? Is this something I can configure in my `knife.rb` or do I have to manually modify the `client.rb` on the node once bootstrap has taken place. Since chef is on the internal network, you're probably right, something is specifically telling chef-client to use the http proxy when it shouldn't. I suppose I'm looking for an 'override' from the the configuration set in 'LAN Settings' on windows.

Comment: Furthermore, should chef-client even use a proxy if not configured in it's client.rb?

Comment: The Windows settings have no effect on Chef or any other Unix-y tools, all proxy config is done via environment variables like HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY.

Comment: Marking as the answer, `no_proxy 'chef.fqdn'` fixes the issue but would be good to identify how the configuration is picked up by chef-client. It seems the work-around for this machine is somehow having the client.rb copied over to node on bootstrap if this is the case.